# Duda sobre labels en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo la interfaz para un código que básicamente son todo operaciones matemáticas básicas, lo que quiero hacer es que una label cambie su texto cuando cambio el texto en entradas y otros labels, algo parecido a una celda de excel, sin necesidad de un botón o algo por el estilo.
Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Hola Masso, deberías agregar un mínimo de código que ilustre los que buscas para tener algo sobre lo que basar la respuesta.  en esencia lo que buscas se hace usando las variables (`tkinter.StringVar`, `tkinter.IntVar`, etc) asociadas a cada widget y dependiendo de lo que busques exactamente hacer uso de `variable.trace_add`.

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que estaba buscando.